# Run entire website in https exclude admin directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to run the entire website in https by excluding the admin folder. For that purpose i have put up the below piece of code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The above code works fine but when i am having the file admin.php or any files which are having a admin keyword in front of file than for those files above .htaccess code treating it as a admin folder so it running that file with http which should be redirected with https as it resides in root of the solution.

so could i make sure that when there is a file with admin keyword which should be treat as a file and redirected in https by not considering it as a admin folder.

Looking forward for your input on this.

Comment: Why not simply add a trailing slash after `admin`? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/`

Comment: When I am adding a / at end of admin (www.mydomain.com/admin/) than when i am opening the admin panel without slash (www.mydomain.com/admin) than it redirect in https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin(?!\.php)
```

Comment: The above suggestion works fine when there is a admin.php file but basically i don't know that which other files will be created in future which started with the admin keyword. for eq. administrator.php, adminlogin.php etc.. so i would like to make sure that in all those cases as well the redirection happen in https.

Comment: @user2746557 Use `!^/admin(?![^/]*\.php)`

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code as this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin.*)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first thing missing is the `RewriteEngine on` instruction.
How can we make redirects if the module isn't enabled?

I don't get why the line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`.
What are you trying to achieve?
To check if it doesn't start with `www`?
If i go to `http://example.com/admin` I wouldn't be redirected.

On the 3rd rule, replacing `!^/admin` with `^/(admin.*)` allows you redirect even if you try to access to, for example, `http://example.com/admin/index.php`.

On your last line, you are relying on the `Host` header, which is set **by the browser**.
This means that this is **unreliable**.
Use `%{SERVER_NAME}` instead, which relies on the machine name itself.

Also, you had `[R=permanent,L]` on your last rule, but it expects a status code.
The code 301 represents a permanent redirect and the browsers will cache it.

---

In case you need, you can go to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test this `.htaccess` code.
Also, you can check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for the documentation of the `.htaccess` redirect module.

Comment: Yes your assumption right here that i have forcefully redirected with www if url not started with the www.

Comment: your suggested changes doesn't work as when i am accessing file like www.mydomain.com/admin.php than it wouldn't redirected with https which actually should be.

Comment: @user2746557 I made a small modification. Can you check it, please?

Comment: @user2746557 We forgot something important: `RewriteEngine on` on the 1st line. It is working now and tested on the latest xampp running on Windows 8.1 Professional x64.

Comment: sorry but i can't seems what changes you have made which works for you

Comment: @user2746557 Sadly, I can't provide a log but if this doesn't work, you are doing something wrong. I can provide print-screens.